# how to logout my application in asp.net c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, logout

When clicking logout button I just used :

```
response.redirect("login.aspx");
```

But the thing is when I click back in browser, it is logging in without entering passwords.

Secondly, my question is how to end this session.

My code snippet is here,

```
 <li><a href="Default.aspx" runat="server" onclick="LogoutClicked()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Log Out</a></li>
```

Thirdly, that is a asp.net page using C#, but I just used an anchor tag that just redirects.

Comment: Are you use WebForms or MVC?

Comment: Please note that [nothing is urgent here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569).

Comment: No.. tats a webform

Answer (score 3):

You need to abandon session so all your sessions should be destroyed after logout
Try this

`Session.Abandon();
Respone.Redirect("Your Url");`

Comment: Onclick () function is not available for anchor tags. I cant araise that in code behind however

Comment: Where you put this line response.redirect("login.aspx"); just above of it use Session.Abandon();